# .NET 4.5.1 update causes 404 error on WCF help page

Tags: .net, wcf, http-status-code-404

1. We have a number of **WCF services** that have been set up to show the user friendly Help page when the **/help extension** is added after the service name (in place of the **.svc**).
2. These recently started returning a 404 error in several of our environments.
3. After some investigation we have discovered that the `.NET 4.5.1` update appears to be the culprit. It has been automatically rolled out on the affected servers and subsequently the /Help pages have ceased working.
4. We have uninstalled the update on one server and reinstalled `.NET 4.0`. Sure enough, the help page starts returning correctly.
5. I really don't want to be in a position where we can't installed .NET updates from this point onwards so I was interested to see if this had affected anyone else and what solutions they might have found.
6. Ideally I would like to have both the `4.5.1 update` and still have the **Help pages operational**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We have a WCF deployment on .NET 4.5.1 and no problems with help page. Could you post your config please?